# better way to counting result and read row in php

Tags: php, mysql

the first, my current code is

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM mytable WHERE something = ".$likethis;
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
```

if the result give 1 or more data, then i do this query to get the data

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM mytable WHERE something = ".$likethis;
```

the second one, another method i found is using this code

```
$totalRow = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

then if give 1 or more, i do fetch the data.

in my head now is, the first one is fast on counting data then only do the rest if have result. but need connect to database twice.
the second one is slower because need to read all data but only connect to database once.

i'm not sure my opinion is accurate it just by how much php read database, and not sure actually which one is better.

or maybe there are other better way to do:
- check how much row it have
- get the rows if have

Comment: you need both count and data in query ..??

Comment: if you want both count and data then use  second-one with `mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: I see no point in doing the count query.  Just execute your actual query and handle an empty result set in your PHP code.

Comment: i want both but not all query will return rows. my current prediction 10-20 percent query will result 0. for example: number of comment, like, and friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `flag` for check you can get row/rows or not. If you can't get any row from database `flag` is true.

For e.g.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from `test`");
$flag = true;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $flag = false;
    // Do stuff.
}
if($flag){
    echo "No record found.";
}
```

> If can not get results code will print else part.

Comment: this seem more simple than my second method. and also i think i can ignore the flag variable for some condition.

Comment: I have use `flag` just for check any row are get from DB or not.